# What is the exact YUM to install Java-JDK?

Tags: linux, unix, installation, java, yum

Do I have to put "multiverse" or something...this is what I heard.
For CENTOS

Comment: For what linux distribution?

Comment: Multiverse is for ubuntu, not centos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not information. You can look at this though, which should help:

http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/JavaOnCentOS